# pass a UIButton into a function

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a function that runs when a button is pressed.

Inside that function is another function.

I would like to pass the pressed button into the inner function so that I can change the text of the button depending on stuff in that inner function.

```
@IBAction func newItem(sender: AnyObject) {
    let urlFetch:String = urlField.text!
    self.service.createNewItem(urlFetch, I_WANT_BUTTON_HERE)
}
```

How do I pass the button into the function?

If it helps this is the function that I am passing it to:

```
func createNewItem(item_url: String, plus_button: UIButton) {
    let dataDictionary = ["url" : item_url]

    self.post("item/create", data: dataDictionary).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
        plus_button.titleLabel!.text = "success"
    }

}
```

Later I will add an if statement that changes the text depending on what the response is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object passed into `newItem` method is actually the button you tapped so you can securely convert the type of parameter `sender` into `UIButton` like below:

```
@IBAction func newItem(sender: UIButton) {
  ...
  self.service.createNewItem(urlFetch, sender)
}
```

There is also one thing though. Setting the text of `titleLabel` is not the right way of updating the title of button. You should be using [`setTitle:forState`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setTitle:forState:) instead:

```
func createNewItem(item_url: String, plus_button: UIButton) {
  ...
  plus_button.setTitle("success", forState: .Normal)
}
```

Comment: `self.service.createNewItem(urlScrape, plus_button: sender)` was necessary, but this pretty much worked, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of sending AnyObject as parameter in the newItem function, pass a UIButton.

```
@IBAction func newItem(sender: UIButton) {
    let urlFetch:String = urlField.text!
    self.service.createNewItem(urlFetch, sender)
}
```